# python take the values in ascending order and delete non increasing values

Tags: python

python program. How do I take the elements in ascending order of a whole list and delete items that do not follow the growth? without using the max as I did here

```
def ascending_num(L1):
    L2 = [L1[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(L1)):
        if L1[i] > max(L1[0:i]):`enter code here
            L2.append(L1[i])
    return L2

print(ascendents_num([2,4,3,5,6,8]))
```

exemple

[2,4,3,5,6,8]

## output

[2, 4, 5, 6, 8]

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: this but I wanted to avoid using the max

Comment: def filtra_ordinati(L1):
    L2 = [L1[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(L1)):
        if L1[i] > max(L1[0:i]):
            L2.append(L1[i])
    return L2

Comment: Then edit your question and use the code filter to make it nice

Comment: How do you know to remove `3` and not `4` here? `[2, 3, 5, 6, 8]` would also seem a valid output

Comment: because the elements 
must be in ascending order and Although there a 4 and 3 after 3 you have to cancel because it does not read element by element and not the entire string at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max can be omitted, you can just iterate through 2 elements at a time, if the next element is greater than the last one it is appended to the new list.

```
li = [2,4,3,5,6,8]
li = [li[0]] + [j for i, j in zip(li, li[1:]) if i < j]
print(li)
```

The zip returns a sequence of tuples with two consecutive elements from the list each, since the second list is shifted by slicing before the second element.

If you want to write it as a function, this is how it can be done:

```
li = [2,4,3,5,6,8]
def eliminate(li):
    return [li[0]] + [j for i, j in zip(li, li[1:]) if i < j]
print(eliminate(li))
```

Comment: Much shorter and avoids the extra `for` loop:`[li[0]] + [j for i,j in zip(li, li[1:]) if i<j]`

Comment: That is true, I will edit my solution. Thanks @NickilMaveli

Comment: if I want to write it in the form of function?

Comment: @FrancescoZito I edited my answer to show how it could be written as a function